# Do VLC or WMP ActiveX controls accept Stream objects?

Tags: c#, activex, vlc, wmp

I've got a WCF service that stories media files and returns them to consuming applications in the form of a Stream object. The issue arises when the consuming application wants to stream the media using MediaElement. As you all know, MediaElement doesn't accept Stream objects.

Can I get around this by using a VLC or WMP ActiveX control? Would either of these two controls allow me to play streaming media?

Comment: Looking here seems yes: http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=18841

Comment: Sound like a valid question but why is it tagged wpf?

Comment: @BalamBalam : Because I need to use the control within a WPF application, and it needs to accept the C# Stream object as its input parameter.

Comment: the fact that it is a WPF application has no bearing on the use case. Either way the C# interface will be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those two activex controls support various types of streaming media, but neither will allow you to use a C# Stream object, which is a managed object. Niether of those two activex controls use any managed code at all, as far as I am aware; it is possible that WMP may, but it wouldn't be exposed via the COM interface in any case.

If memory serves, I think you can provide a MediaElement with individual frames (even H.264 frames), so you could possibly extract the stream yourself and feed it into the MediaObject.

Comment: Hi! Could u point to any link around you said: "
, I think you can provide a MediaElement with individual frames (even H.264 frames), so you could possibly extract the stream yourself and feed it into the MediaObject.", please?

Comment: Sure can't.  I remember seeing something about it, but I haven't looked at it in so long I don't have any links