# Can I use System.IO.Stream with an ActiveX VLC control?

Tags: c#, wpf, activex, vlc

I'm thinking about using VLC as an ActiveX control for my WPF application, but I'm unsure of whether or not it would accept a `System.IO.Stream` object as an input parameter and be able to stream media that way. I haven't been able to find any definitive answers to this, so before I actually go ahead with this, I'd like to be sure that VLC can do this.

The `System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement` is out of the question for me since it only accepts URIs as input parameters for the source. The same goes for AxWindowsMediaPlayer, which I thought would work.

Comment: Why did you ask this question multiple times? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134135/wpf-do-vlc-or-wmp-activex-controls-accept-stream-objects/7142490#7142490

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be able to accept "non-primitive" types such as streams. These are .Net types which haves no direct analogue in COM. It would have to have been explicitly designed to work with streams via COM interop.

Comment: Does it accept byte[]? I can call Stream.BeginRead, which reads the stream into the byte[] buffer which I'll then pass into the VLC ActiveX control.

Comment: Perhaps you should be asking, how do I use VLC with C#.

Comment: That's another issue... I haven't been able to find any C# documentation for libvlc. Otherwise it would've been a lot simpler to have a look at what options I've got. So far, it doesn't look like it'll be able to play a stream using a byte array.

Comment: I have answered your question.